# Only when all statuses the same than return result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am selecting `Q_GRADEBOOK_ID` if **all the status against** `Q_GRADEBOOK_ID` is 488 than return `Q_GRADEBOOK_ID` otherwise return empty

```
TABLE Q_GB_CAT_SCORE
---------------------------------------------------------
 Q_GRADEBOOK_ID | PERSON_ID | STATUS | Q_GRADEBOOK_CAT_ID
      1         |     1     |  488   |       1
      1         |     1     |  488   |       2
      1         |     2     |  488   |       1
      2         |     2     |  486   |       1
      2         |     2     |  488   |       2
```

**My Query**

```
 SELECT
 DISTINCT 
 Q_GRADEBOOK_ID 
 FROM 
 Q_GB_CAT_SCORE WHERE
 STATUS IN ('488')
```

This query return this result

```
Q_GRADEBOOK_ID
      1        
      2
```

**Expected Result**

```
Q_GRADEBOOK_ID
      1
```

I expect it because `Q_GRADEBOOK_ID` 1 return because against `Q_GRADEBOOK_ID` 1 all the status is 488.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude ID with different status:

```
SELECT distinct 
 Q_GRADEBOOK_ID
  FROM Q_GB_CAT_SCORE
 WHERE Q_GRADEBOOK_ID not in
        (select distinct Q_GRADEBOOK_ID FROM Q_GB_CAT_SCORE WHERE status <> '488')
```

Comment: @Adam fixed expression

Comment: Why you not used distinct for Q_GRADEBOOK_ID

Answer (score 1):

You can `GROUP BY Q_GRADEBOOK_ID` and put the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT Q_GRADEBOOK_ID 
FROM Q_GB_CAT_SCORE 
GROUP BY Q_GRADEBOOK_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = '488' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or

```
SELECT Q_GRADEBOOK_ID 
FROM Q_GB_CAT_SCORE 
GROUP BY Q_GRADEBOOK_ID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS <> '488' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```